# DatePicker: both textbox and button get keyboard focus?

Tags: wpf, focus, datepicker

Is there a way to get focus on *both* controls in the WPF DatePicker? Setting the Focusable property on both makes neither work.

We would like users to be able to tab to both controls instead of focus only going to the textbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help on this. I needed to set the KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation property to "Continue", then it worked. Thanks to Sam for the fix.